# Is there a way to combine two mysql fields that are of the "set" type?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to combine two fields... both of the set type?

```
field1 is ('c')
field2 is ('a')
```

I want to select the field so that it returns 'a,c'

I've tried `concat`, but it returns duplicates in the set.
so if field 2 was ('a','c') it would return 'a,c,c'

I've also tried `field1 & field2`, but because this is a set it returns the decimal value.

Comment: Sounds to me like using `set` was a bad idea.

Comment: probably, but I can't change that now.

Answer (score 1):

Try `field1 | field2` instead of `field1 & field2`

```
mysql> create table test (id serial, foo set('a','b','c') not null, bar set('a','b','c') not null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into test (foo,bar) values('a,c','c,b'),('b,a','a'),('a,b','b,c');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test;
+----+-----+-----+
| id | foo | bar |
+----+-----+-----+
|  1 | a,c | b,c |
|  2 | a,b | a   |
|  3 | a,b | b,c |
+----+-----+-----+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> update test set foo = foo | bar;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.16 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test;
+----+-------+-----+
| id | foo   | bar |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | a,b,c | b,c |
|  2 | a,b   | a   |
|  3 | a,b,c | b,c |
+----+-------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1 but I bet this depends on both SET columns having the same elements. Or at least `bar` being the left-prefix of `foo`.

Comment: Yes, yes it would. The original question mentioned duplicates, so I was working with the assumption the column definitions were the same. If that's incorrect, so's my answer!